# Side menu not covering all screen (DrawerNavigator - React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, side-menu

I adding image of screen, this work in part of screen.
The Contacts screen need to be main page and not screen1 but its didn't work if i replace between them.
I adding the code, in 'LogedInNavigator' have there TabNavigator and DrawerNavigator - the 'Contants' page initializing from TabNavigator and part two - Screen1 with the side menu it's from DrawerNavigator - maybe it's doing the problem?
[image]

LogedInNavigator.js

```
import.......
styles......

const LoggedInNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Contacts: {screen: ContactScreen,},
    Chat: {screen: ChatScreen,},
    Dashbaord: {screen: DashbaordScreen,},
    Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen,},
    Search: {screen: SearchScreen,},
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName: "Contacts", 
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor: 'white',
    }
  }
);

export default () => <LoggedInNavigator onNavigationStateChange={null} />

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator ({
  Home:{
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer:{
        label: 'Home',
      },
    }
  },  
  Camera: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer:{
        label: 'Camera',
      },
    }
  }, 
})
```

Contants.js

```
class Contacts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // TBD loggedin should come from login process and removed from here
    const { loggedIn, getContacts } = this.props;
    loggedIn(1);
    getContacts();
  }

  render() {
    const Router = createRouter( () => ({})); //IDAN 
    const { navigation, avatar, contacts } = this.props;
    return (
      <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <ContactView
            navigation={navigation}
            avatar={avatar}
            contacts={contacts}
          />
         <Drawer />
        </View>
      </NavigationProvider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return (
    {
      avatar: state.user.user.avatar,
      contacts: state.contacts.contacts,
    }
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loggedIn, getContacts })(Contacts);
```

Help me please..

Comment: if you want your drawer to cover full screen, you will probably need to make a custom component for a drawer

Comment: And what be in this component? i need the Contacts page in main page..

Comment: whatever you need, check the official docs of react-navigation

Comment: what i can do to connect the Contacts page ? the TabNavigator initial page and DrawerNavigator initail too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**After a while, i want to answer on my own question** (with `react-navigation` v2)
everything inside `<RootNavigator/>`

```
const RootNavigator= createDrawerNavigator({ Tabs }, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width * .75,
})
```

SideMenu:

```
class SideMenu extends Component {
   render() {
        return ( //...your side menu view )
   }
}
```

Tab:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    Menu: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'תפריט',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                return <Icon name={'home'} size={20} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        }
    },
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'בית',
            tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => handleTabPress(navigation, defaultHandler),
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                return <Icon name={'dashboard'} size={20} color={'green'} />;
            },
        }
    },
    QuickView: {
        screen: QuickNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'מבט מהיר',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                return <Icon name={'short-list'} size={20} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        },
    },
    Chat: {
        screen: Chat,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "צ'אט",
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                return <Icon name={'chat'} size={20} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        },
    },
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'green',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 16,
                marginBottom: 3,
            },
        },
    },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For v5 onwards you can use drawer style

```
import deviceInfoModule from 'react-native-device-info';


 <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerStyle={{
            width: deviceInfoModule.isTablet()
              ? Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.55
              : Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.7,
          }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In react-navigation version 6, you can use the **drawerStyle** in the **screenOptions** prop in the **Drawer.Navigator** component to change the width and add styles. This applies the applied style to all screens in the navigator.

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions: {{
    drawerStyle: {
      width: 240
    }
  }}
>
```

If you want the drawer to cover the entire screen, then import **Dimensions** from the **react-native** library and use **Dimensions.get('window').width**

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions: {{
    drawerStyle: {
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width
    }
  }}
>
```

Refer to [react-navigation drawer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the drawer width using Dimensions width. See the docs here

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

...

const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');

...

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator (
{
  Home:{
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer:{
        label: 'Home',
      },
    }
  },  
  Camera: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer:{
        label: 'Camera',
      },
    }
  }, 
},
{
  drawerWidth: width
});
```

Comment: It don't work...
the Width mine to the menu after open..so its open it all of the width screen but it still on same place